# Linq To Entities Subquery, Limiting the results in the subquery

Tags: linq-to-entities, subquery, limit

I'm working on my final assignment to the Minor I'm following, I'm trying to retrieve a list of Artists, of which each have multiple Albums, of which each have multiple Tracks. Of that selection, I'm tasked with only selecting a certain number of tracks per album, not all of them. And that is where I am stuck.

So far, my attempts have landed me this:

```
var result = (from ta in db.ARTIEST
join tb in db.ALBUM on ta.ARTIEST_ID equals tb.ARTIEST_ID
join tc in db.TRACK on tb.ALBUM_ID equals tc.ALBUM_ID
where tb.TITEL == param && (
         from td in db.TRACK
         where td.ALBUM_ID == tb.ALBUM_ID
         select td.ALBUM_ID
         ).Take(3).Contains(tb.ALBUM_ID)
select ta);
```

Basically, my question is, how can I build a query with Linq to Entities that joins 2 tables to the Artiest table while limiting the selected results from the 3rd table to 3 records?

Comment: What is your starting point? Did you make an EF model? Code-first, database-first?

Comment: I made a EF model with Database first. The 3 entities I am connecting are all in the database, and in the model. They follow the following connection: Artiest 1->n Album 1->n Track.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest is to use a navigation property between album and tracks:

```cs
from artist in db.Artists
join album in db.Albums on artist.ARTIEST_ID equals album.ARTIEST_ID
where album.TITEL == param
select new { artist, album, FirstTracks = album.Tracks.Take(3) }
```